# MVC Core pass LINQ object to iPagedList

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass a select new {} to a view using the following:

```cs
var results = 
    (from n in _context.Nodes
    join o in _context.Organizations on n.OrgId equals o.Id
    join t in _context.Organizations on n.ContractingOrgId equals t.Id

    select new
    {
        Id = n.Id,
        Name = n.Name,
        assigned_org = o.ShortName,
        con_org_short_name = t.ShortName,
        expiry = n.ExpireDate,
        lastActive = n.ActiveDate
    });
            
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    results = results.Where(s => s.con_org_short_name.Contains(searchString)
                            || s.Id.ToString().StartsWith(searchString));
}

switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "Client_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.con_org_short_name);
        break;
    case "Client":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.con_org_short_name);
        break;
    case "Assigned":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.assigned_org);
        break;
    case "Assigned_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.assigned_org);
        break;
    case "Expires":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.expiry);
        break;
    case "Expires_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.expiry);
        break;
    case "LastActive":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.lastActive);
        break;
    case "LastActive_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.lastActive);
        break;
    case "Id_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);
        break;
    default:
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
        break;
};
int pageSize = 12;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
return View(await results.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

This throws an error at return View()

> "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'X.PagedList.StaticPagedList`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`6[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'X.PagedList.IPagedList`1[AdminPortal.Models.Node]'.

And I get a build error on these lines:

```cs
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    results = results.Where(s => s.con_org_short_name.Contains(searchString)
                            || s.Id.ToString().StartsWith(searchString));
}
```

In the ienumerable visualiser on 'results' the object is shown in the first column as an anonymous type and it looks like an array but it has the expected output.

The question is, how to I access just that object and pass it to the return View() in the correct type?

This is the view to which the results are supposed to be passed:

```html
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<AdminPortal.Models.Node>
@using X.PagedList;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;
<link href="~/css/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="row pt-4">
    <div class=" col-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="text-white">Node List</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class=" row pt-4" style="padding-bottom:10px">
        <div class=" col-6">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Nodes", FormMethod.Get))
            {
               <p>
                    Find by name/id: @Html.TextBox("SearchString",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, htmlAttributes: new  {style="background-color:#cef2eb"})
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class=" btn btn-info" />
               </p>

                
            }
        </div>

        <div class=" col-6 text-end">
            <a asp-controller="Nodes" asp-action="Create" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> &nbsp; Create Node
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
            <tr style="color:#126E75; background-color:lightcyan">
            <th class=col-sm-1 style="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IDSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-2 style ="text-align:left">
                Node Name
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-1 style="text-align:left">
                Mode
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-2 style ="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("Assigned To", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AssignedSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
             </th>
            <th class=col-sm-2 style ="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("Contracting Org", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ClientSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-1 style ="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("Expires", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ExpiresSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-1 style ="text-align:left">
                    @Html.ActionLink("LastActive", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastActiveSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2" style=" width:10%; text-align:center">
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr class="table-light">
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsStudy)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Org.ShortName)
            </td>
            <td align ="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractingOrg.ShortName)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpireDate)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActiveDate)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" style="color:blue"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class=" col-12 text-end">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

Comment: Share your `ToPagedListAsync()` generic method code too

Comment: @KiranJoshi  Which code do you want me to share?  Do you mean the View?

Comment: Yes view and `ToPagedListAsync()` Method as well

Comment: @KiranJoshi  ToPagedListAsync() is a c# method like ToListAsync() so I didn't write the method and therefore can't share it with you. It is what is used if you want to use pagination in the associated view.

Comment: You have to share the View code at least so I can provide a solution

Comment: @KiranJoshi  Posted edited to include View Code.

Comment: can you please check what exactly your  `await results.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize)` return? There might be an issue it as per your exception message. What is the return type of `ToPagedList()`?

Comment: @KiranJoshi  If you scroll up the post a bit you'll see the error message.

Comment: Which Nuget package you are using for `ToPagedList()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one solution for your problem.

View Model

```
NodeViewModel.CS

public class NodeViewModel
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string assigned_org {get;set;}
  public string con_org_short_name {get;set;}
  public string expiry  {get;set;}
  public string lastActive  {get;set;}
}
```

Controller method:

```
var results = 
    (from n in _context.Nodes
    join o in _context.Organizations on n.OrgId equals o.Id
    join t in _context.Organizations on n.ContractingOrgId equals t.Id

    select new NodeViewModel
    {
        Id = n.Id,
        Name = n.Name,
        assigned_org = o.ShortName,
        con_org_short_name = t.ShortName,
        expiry = n.ExpireDate,
        lastActive = n.ActiveDate
    });
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    results = results.Where(s => s.con_org_short_name.Contains(searchString)
                            || s.Id.ToString().StartsWith(searchString));
}

switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "Client_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.con_org_short_name);
        break;
    case "Client":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.con_org_short_name);
        break;
    case "Assigned":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.assigned_org);
        break;
    case "Assigned_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.assigned_org);
        break;
    case "Expires":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.expiry);
        break;
    case "Expires_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.expiry);
        break;
    case "LastActive":
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.lastActive);
        break;
    case "LastActive_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.lastActive);
        break;
    case "Id_desc":
        results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);
        break;
    default:
        results = results.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
        break;
};
int pageSize = 12;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
return View(await results.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

View

```
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<NodeViewModel>
@using X.PagedList;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;
<link href="~/css/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="row pt-4">
    <div class=" col-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="text-white">Node List</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class=" row pt-4" style="padding-bottom:10px">
        <div class=" col-6">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Nodes", FormMethod.Get))
            {
               <p>
                    Find by name/id: @Html.TextBox("SearchString",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, htmlAttributes: new  {style="background-color:#cef2eb"})
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class=" btn btn-info" />
               </p>

                
            }
        </div>

        <div class=" col-6 text-end">
            <a asp-controller="Nodes" asp-action="Create" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> &nbsp; Create Node
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
            <tr style="color:#126E75; background-color:lightcyan">
            <th class=col-sm-1 style="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IDSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-2 style ="text-align:left">
                Node Name
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-1 style="text-align:left">
                Mode
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-2 style ="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("Assigned To", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AssignedSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
             </th>
            <th class=col-sm-2 style ="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("Contracting Org", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ClientSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-1 style ="text-align:left">
                @Html.ActionLink("Expires", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ExpiresSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th class=col-sm-1 style ="text-align:left">
                    @Html.ActionLink("LastActive", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastActiveSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2" style=" width:10%; text-align:center">
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr class="table-light">
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsStudy)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Org.ShortName)
            </td>
            <td align ="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractingOrg.ShortName)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpireDate)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActiveDate)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" style="color:blue"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class=" col-12 text-end">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

after making all above changes your view will be working like charm

Comment: Works like a charm as you said.  I can't thank you enough.  This has just opened up a whole new world of possibilities to me.  I need to do a 5 table join so I should be able to crack it with this method.  Thanks again!!!